# How Can I stop neo4j community edition in kubernetes?

Tags: docker, neo4j, kubernetes, containers

I have put neo4j community edition(v3.2.2) into kubernetes. But the community edition do not support hot backup so I have to shut it down for backup/restore data.

I tried:

```
kubectl exec neo4j-0 /var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j stop
```

but it shows:

```
Neo4j not running
```

also tried:

```
kubectl exec -it neo4j-0 bash
/var/lib/neo4j/bin/neo4j stop
```

but still can't stop the neo4j in container

```
Neo4j not running
```

Does any body have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can not stop the main process inside a container, otherwise it will be considered as dead and Kubernetes will terminate this pod and schedule a new healthy one.

Also Kubernetes does not support suspending pods. It's cheaper to stop/start pods.

So, in your case, I'd recommend to down scale you deployment to zero replicas during backup

```
kubectl scale --replicas=0 deployment/neo4j
```

and up scale back to required replicas once backup is completed

```
kubectl scale --replicas=1 deployment/neo4j
```

Comment: it just saying 'Neo4j not running'. But I can still access neo4j on browser

Comment: @Miko can you share your deployment manifest, so I could try to reproduce

Comment: Sure, I added it in my question

Comment: If change the replica to 0, then I can't get into the pod to execute neo4j command to do the backup job. So I think it's no work for this case.

Answer (score 1):

For now, `offlineMaintenanceModeEnabled` is available for Neo4j's Helm chart.

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/kubernetes/maintenance/#put-offline-mode

You can control the offline maintenance mode by setting `neo4j.offlineMaintenanceModeEnabled` in Helm's `values.yaml` to `true` and `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The dump/load commands are strictly offline operations, while backup/restore are online operations.

I got another solution by creating another pod with the same image, then i scaled down the statefulset replicas to 0 of neo4j and mounted the volume consued by the statefulset.

After i created the dump file, I needed to push it to aurora neo4j by using the plugin **push-to-cloud**, download the same version otherwise it won't work

This is my yaml file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
name: neo4j-dumper
spec:
 containers:
   - name: neo4j-dumper
     image: neo4j:3.5.23-enterprise
     command:[
      "sh",
      "-c",
      "mkdir /dump && neo4j-admin dump --to /dump/db.dump && chown -R neo4j /dump && sleep 30000;",
    ]
  volumeMounts:
    - name: datadir
      mountPath: /data
volumes:
  - name: datadir
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: datadir-neo4j-neo4j-core-0
```